# Why is defaultCommandTimeout not working in my script

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I know there is this solution of adding `defaultCommandTimeout` in the cypress.json file, but I do not want to add wait everywhere in my entire test framework.

I only need to only wait for one particular element.

```js
    add.getCountry().type('India');
    Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout', 10000);
    add.selectCountry().click();
```

Cypress result:

[image: cypress result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add timeouts to individual cypress commands, something like:

```js
cy.get('.suggestions > ul > li > a', { timeout: 10000 }).should('be.visible')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working :). May I know why Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout', 10000); is not working?

Comment: `Cypress.config()` overrides the value of `cypress.json`. You can read from here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Test-Configuration. So for this to work you need to first add `defaultCommandTimeout', 10000` to your `cypress.json`

Comment: Hello sir, can you helpme on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71235183 please?

Answer (score 5):

A better way to change the timeout is in the test header, like this:

```js
it('tests my slow suggestion form', {defaultCommandTimeout: 10_000}, () => {
  // test code that relies on 
})
```

That way any command within the test is seeing the longer timeout.

Even better, add a `cy.intercept()` with a mock response to bypass the slow API calls. That way, you don't have to worry about timeouts as the standard 4 seconds works fine, and your tests will run faster.